# How do I have a Swift application run as root on launch?

Tags: swift, macos, unix, root, swiftui

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  Jupiter
//
//  Created by SmushyTaco on 9/16/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 SmushyTaco. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                let installNano = Process()
                installNano.launchPath = "/opt/pkg/bin/pkgin"
                installNano.arguments = ["-y", "install", "nano"]
                installNano.launch()
            }) {
            Text("Install Nano")
            }
//            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                let removeNano = Process()
                removeNano.launchPath = "/opt/pkg/bin/pkgin"
                removeNano.arguments = ["-y", "remove", "nano"]
                removeNano.launch()
            }) {
            Text("Remove Nano")
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I'm making a macOS application with **SwiftUI** which will be a frontend for the pkgin package manager and to do things like install packages with this package manager you need root so how do I make this application launch with root permissions without the use of any unsafe code (Like C code since that's an unsafe language), without asking for the users password every time the application launches (If possible), and without using anything that's been deprecated?

Comment: Isn't this more of a Mac OS or Unix question rather than a programming question?

Comment: You must **take** the permission from the user.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini how would I do so?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Updated tags